# Can a tkinter python program be mirrored on an android app

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a python program that displays the time, weather, and anything else that would be suitable to be put in an information center. Is it possible to run this program natively on android and get live updates like the python program?

I've googled it and haven't been able to find anything close to an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "mirror"? Do you want to run the app natively, or do you want to connect the android app to a running app on the desktop?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't remember the word, yes I would like it to run natively on android.

Comment: You might want to look into [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) for this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot run tkinter programs on the android platform.